# Upload file to s3 after compression

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I am developing upload functionality to S3 using springboot and aws api but I am not able to compress the file .

Below is code and pleaset tell how to compress in my code

```
public ApiResponse<?> uploadFile(MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
        logger.info("------------Start:: UploadFileService :uploadFileToS3-----------------");
        String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
        FileUploadEntity fileUploadEntityResult = null;
        ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(file.getBytes());
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(fileName) && ObjectUtils.isNotEmpty(inputStream)) {
            ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
            objectMetadata.setSSEAlgorithm(ObjectMetadata.AES_256_SERVER_SIDE_ENCRYPTION);
            PutObjectRequest putRequest = new PutObjectRequest("kads-property-documents", fileName, inputStream, objectMetadata)
                    .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
            try {
                PutObjectResult putObjectResult = amazonS3EncryptionV2.putObject(putRequest);

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "compress the file"? Are you wanting to convert it into a Zip file and store that Zip file on S3?

Comment: Yes @JohnRotenstein